# Docker overrides the IP address of my own manually created bridge

Tags: docker, bridge, docker-network

I am trying to **set docker up to connect all containers to my own manually created bridge (br0)**, I don't want docker to create or edit anything in my bridge, because I have other services which uses and depends on my bridge (like OpenVPN) therefore I prefer to create the bridge using my own bash script.

The problem comes when I start docker service, **docker changes my bridge IP address** from what I want **(192.168.1.10)** to something else address(169.254.x.x)!!!

**My Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638**

## The steps I did

### Bridge creation:

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo ip addr del 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev br0 
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
```

I also deleted the default docker0 brdige.

### Tell docker to use my br0 instead of the default docker0:

Passing ***-b br0*** parameter to dockerd.service starting script to tell docker that I want him to use my br0:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/overlay.conf
```

I edited ExecStart to be like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-driver=overlay -H fd:// -b=br0
```

and then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

And now when I check my **br0 IP, it is NOT 192.168.1.10 any more, it is back to 172.17.x.x**, and when I try to change it now manually back to 192.168.1.10, the interfaces in containers keeps using 169.254.x.x instead of the IP I want.

P.s. when I check where are the interfaces of my containers: `brctl show`, **they are really in my br0** (that means docker accepted -b br0 paramter, but it just ignores or override my intended IP address).

Could some one help me please to over come that problem? it looks for me like a bug maybe. I just want docker to use my br0 with the intended IP address 192.168.1.10.

My need is that all my containers get and IP address in the range I want.
Thanks in advance.

## Edited:

### My /var/log/daemon.log

```
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi dockerd[976]: time="2016-10-10T20:41:12.067551389Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Oct 10 20:41:12 raspberrypi dockerd[976]: time="2016-10-10T20:41:12.128388194Z" level=info msg="stopping containerd after receiving terminated"
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:41:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[698]: br0: removing IP address 169.254.124.135/16
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:41:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[698]: br0: deleting route to 169.254.0.0/16
Oct 10 20:41:52 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #7 br0, 169.254.124.135#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=516 secs
Oct 10 20:41:52 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:42:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:43:00 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 8 br0 192.168.1.19 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:43:00 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Oct 10 20:43:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 10 20:44:31 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:31.887581128Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1543"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.903109872Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"overlay\""
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.950908429Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951611338Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951800086Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951906179Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.951993522Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.952173520Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.952372059Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.953406319Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.970612440Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.953406319Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 10 20:44:32 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:32.970612440Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715576231Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715837582Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715921435Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=23cf638 graphdriver=overlay version=1.12.1
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.754984356Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 9 br0 169.254.124.135 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #8 br0, 192.168.1.19#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=94 secs
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: peers refreshed
```

The interesting part is the last part (I recopied it here bellow):

```
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.19 on br0.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.19.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Interface br0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 169.254.124.135.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 169.254.124.135 on br0.IPv4.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715576231Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715837582Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.715921435Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=23cf638 graphdriver=overlay version=1.12.1
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 10 20:44:33 raspberrypi dockerd[1536]: time="2016-10-10T20:44:33.754984356Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Listen normally on 9 br0 169.254.124.135 UDP 123
Oct 10 20:44:34 raspberrypi ntpd[723]: Deleting interface #8 br0, 192.168.1.19#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=94
```

Comment: Could you try running the docker service manually with -b and revert changes to ExecStart just to rule out that it is not a script problem?

Comment: Actually I just added -b to the script nothing more, anyway I tried to do that but I with now success because linux told me that I have to use start script (systenctl) to start docker

Answer (score 0):

Once the docker container is running the network configuration is not editable. Try running your docker container with `--bip=CIDR` and set your bridge ip manually. For more info follow [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/).

Comment: My docker service is completely stopper before doing anything, eventually my containers, --bip=CIDR cannot be used at the same time with -b. --bip=CIDR alone will work just in case I want to use the default docker0 with a new IP (I have already tried that and docker didn't accept to start because the two mentioned params cannot be used at the same time), but as I said, I want to use my own completely independent bridge br0, not just customize docker0 (the link you sent).

Comment: Have you followed http://54.71.194.30:4017/articles/networking/#bridge-building ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same what I did (I just notified docker somewhere else about -b parameter as the link is apparently old, and I ignored iptables step because it is not important for my problem).